# Why are natural numbers defined with union in Zermelo–Fraenkel (ZF) set theory?

Tags: set-theory, natural-numbers

In Zermelo–Fraenkel (ZF) set theory, the natural numbers are defined as $0 = \emptyset$ and $n + 1 = n \cup \{n\}$

$$\begin{alignat}{2}
   0 & {} = \{\} && {} = \emptyset,\\
   1 & {} = \{0\} && {} = \{\emptyset\},\\
   2 & {} = \{0,1\} && {} = \{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\},\\
   3 & {} = \{0,1,2\} && {} = \{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\},\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}\}
 \end{alignat}$$

My intuition would be, to define it as $0 = \emptyset$ and $n + 1 = \{n\}$

$$\begin{alignat}{0}
   0 && = \emptyset,\\
   1 && = \{\emptyset\},\\
   2 && = \{\{\emptyset\}\},\\
   3 && = \{\{\{\emptyset\}\}\}
 \end{alignat}$$

Why is it defined that way? What makes it more straightforward than my definition?

Comment: Don't you like $2$ being a two-element set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zermelo's original definition of the natural numbers was actually your "intuitive" definition – it's not a new idea. The standard definition (the first one) is due to von Neumann, and is used because it makes defining *order* on the natural numbers much easier using the subset relation.

For example, $3\le5$ because the von Neumann representation of $3$, $\{0,1,2\}$, is a subset of the representation of $5$, $\{0,1,2,3,4\}$. Doing the same with Zermelo ordinals, in which $3\equiv\{\{\{\{\}\}\}\}$ and $5\equiv\{\{\{\{\{\{\}\}\}\}\}\}$, is very finicky.

The von Neumann ordinals also have the nice property that each number is matched to a set containing that many elenents, so they serve as representatives for *cardinalities*.